# Spring Datasource.Username cached on AWS EC2, not locally?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I have a Spring boot application running on EC2. Recently we shifted database usernames. The username for my instance changed and I updated it in the application.properties file. Ran `mvn clean install`, got the jar, scp'ed it up to the EC2, and restarted the service.

I am getting the error that `password authentication failed for user "old_user_name"` even after restarting the service with the new .jar.

I've so far verified that:

- The `target` directory has an application.properties file with the correct username
- The service is running and endpoints which do not require data access function
- When built locally the data access layer works with the new username

The EC2 is configured per the instructions [here](https://zoltanaltfatter.com/2016/12/17/spring-boot-application-on-ec2/) with a background user having the application start. The only thing I can think is that `service *name* restart` on the server is preserving old application.properties values. Is there a way to easily clear these cached values, or force the service to watch changes to the properties file?

Comment: There is no "value cache" like you are talking about. Are you sure you changed the correct setting in the properties file? Is a different properties file being loaded due to the active Spring Boot profile on the server? Are you sure you copied the jar file to the correct location on the EC2 server?

Comment: I've changed both spring.datasource.username and spring.datasource.password to the new values. I will check active profiles, thank you. The jar is in the correct directory and is linked to the correct service